# Combining two dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++

There are two dynamically allocated arrays, and I need to merge them into one. Here is the code, but it is not correct:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    system("chcp 1251>null");
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int* a = new int[n];
    int* b = new int[m];
    int* w = new int[n + m];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        w[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n+m; i++) {
        w[i] = (i < m ? a[i] : b[i - n - 1]);
        cout<<w[i]<<" ";
    }
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] w;
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

How to fix it to be like this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [1,2,5,6]
W [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

NO USING SET OR VECTOR

Comment: use vector<int>?

Comment: Use `std::set` to get unique and ordered values quickly

Comment: @OznOg no using vector

Comment: why dont you want to use vector?

Comment: Your example shows `A` and `B` containing duplicates that don't exist in the combined `W`, but your code does not ignore duplicates when populating `W`.

Comment: @OznOg I'm just learning, so I started the topic of arrays, so I leave the vectors for later

Comment: Are your data inputs always ordered?

Comment: vectors will be easier. You have started learning a more difficult concept.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How to fix?

Comment: @TUIlover Not always, but I can sort myself

Comment: @drescherjm Understood, but still wanted to bring it to an end

Comment: What is the exact thing you want to achieve : concatenation two arrays and remove duplicates?

Comment: @drescherjm So I understood, but as with A and B in the conclusion to make shob elements were not repeated

Comment: @TUIlover Well, I combined, and I need to delete those that are repeated

Comment: Combine doesn’t make sense. Do you want it ordered by values or by index of the original arrays?

Comment: The time complexity you would get without using set would be much higher. It would be O(n*m) but with set you can reduce this to O(nlogm).

Comment: @TUIlover by values

Comment: I wonder if titles of threads should have in them what cannot be used.  Anyone searching for this topic will come across this question, and be disappointed if they do not see the answer that uses `std::set`.  Clearly stating what cannot be used up front, whether in the title or in the question, should be emphasized (IMO) so that searchers are not wasting their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows `A` and `B` containing duplicates that don't exist in the combined `W`, but your code does not ignore duplicates when populating `W`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    system("chcp 1251>null");
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int* a = new int[n];
    int* b = new int[m];
    int* w = new int[n + m];
    int k = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
        w[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        for(; j < k; ++j) {
            if (w[j] == b[i]) break;    
        }
        if (j == k) {
            w[k++] = b[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        cout << w[i] << " ";
    }
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] w;
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/xMqvBr)

Comment: for some reason my garbage comes out on the last element

Comment: Did you loop to `k` in your cout like the code shows: `for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {` You can't have m+n there.

Comment: @sobaka13 Well, that is something you are going to have to debug for yourself. The code I have provided works with the input you have provided, as demonstrated by the [working demo](https://ideone.com/xMqvBr).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, I still have copies of the elements in the compiler

Comment: Now if there were duplicated numbers in the array `a` they would still exist.

Comment: @drescherjm Of course, I fixed the error when outputting W, but still copies of the elements

Comment: You probably will have to show an example how this code fails. I don't see it.

Comment: @drescherjm I entered: 1 2 3 - the first array, 1 4 5 - the second array and output 1 1 1 4 3 5

Comment: @drescherjm you forgot to provide input values for `n` and `m`, the input for that program would need to be `3 3 1 2 3 1 4 5` instead of `1 2 3 1 4 5`

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry, I already solved the problem, it was in the project, what a mistake (cannot use C) well, I recreated the project and everything worked out, thank you

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I already solved the problem, it was in the project, what a mistake (cannot use C) well, I recreated the project and everything worked out, thank you

Comment: I figured that out and updated: [https://ideone.com/rQRsGX](https://ideone.com/rQRsGX) I got distracted by a conversation while testing..

Answer (score 0):

1. to merge two lists efficiently, they need to be sorted first
2. use vector instead of raw arrays
3. use std::merge() to merge two sorted lists, but it doesn't remove duplicates
4. use std::unique() to remove duplicates on a sorted range
5. don't forget to erase the range that unique() returns to the vector's end, to actually remove the space that was made free by uniquing:

Or instead of merging two sorted lists, you can append one list on the other, then sort the whole thing, and then remove dupes.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 2, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> b{1, 4, 5, 5, 6};

    // result is copy of a with contents of b appended to its end
    std::vector<int> result(a);
    result.insert(end(result), begin(b), end(b));

    std::sort(begin(result), end(result));
    result.erase(std::unique(begin(result), end(result)), end(result));

    for (int elt : result) {
        std::cout << elt << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But if this is homework, you're going to have to write the merge logic yourself, and walk both lists simultaneously, picking the lowest value from either and appending it to your result, and if it's equal to the previous, drop it and continue.

Comment: The OP said that `vector` is not to be used. Which likely means algorithms like `merge()` and `unique()` are off-limits, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The question was changed after I wrote this.  It originally only said "NOT USING SET"

Comment: The OP said in comments "no using vector" an hour before you posted your answer.

Comment: That has no bearing on the algorithm, which is what the question is really about.  I'd prefer not to argue about such a pointless topic as this.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that a and b are already sorted :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    system("chcp 1251>null");
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int* a = new int[n];
    int* b = new int[m];
    int* w = new int[n + m];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while (i<n && j<m){
        if (a[i]==b[j]){
            w[k]=a[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            }
        else{
            w[k] = a[i]<b[j]? a[i++]:b[j++];
            }
        k++;
        }
    while (i < n){
        w[k++]=a[i++];
        }
    while (j<m){
        w[k++]=b[j++];
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout<<w[i]<<" ";
    }
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] w;
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```